# Does thetaf() in the forecast package in R detect seasonality?

Tags: r, forecasting, theta-method

I had a question on the theta method in the `forecast` package in `R`. I tried using the `AirPassenger` example with `thetaf()`, but it just provided a trend line without seasonality in the forecast. Does `thetaf()` detect and forecast seasonality?

This is the `R` code that I used:

```
library(forecast)
x.fit4 <- thetaf(AirPassengers, h=24)
plot(x.fit4)
```

Comment: This question was answered by Prof Hyndman.                    Theta method does not handle seasonality.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @forecaster. This question seems to be *only* about how R deals w/ this. As such, it would be off-topic for CV (see our [help page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help)), but on-topic on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). If you have a question about the statistical issues w/ this, please edit to clarify; if not, flag your Q & we'll migrate it for you (*please don't cross-post, though*).

Answer (score 6):

The theta method does not handle seasonality. If you read the help file for `thetaf` you will see that it says

> The theta method of Assimakopoulos and Nikolopoulos (2000) is
>   equivalent to simple exponential smoothing with drift.

If you want a method that detects trend and seasonality, use either `ets` or `auto.arima`.

Answer (score 0):

The theta model does not handle seasonality by itself, but the `thetaf` function in the forecast package does. If you read the help file for thetaf, you will see the following:

> The theta method of Assimakopoulos and Nikolopoulos (2000) is equivalent to simple exponential smoothing with drift. This is demonstrated in Hyndman and Billah (2003).
>
> **The series is tested for seasonality** using the test outlined in A&N. If deemed seasonal, **the series is seasonally adjusted** using a classical multiplicative decomposition before applying the theta method. The resulting forecasts are then reseasonalized.

([Source](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.7/topics/thetaf).)

If you [read the theta model paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Vassilis_Assimakopoulos/publication/223049702_The_theta_model_A_decomposition_approach_to_forecasting/links/5a7e3b2daca272a73765ccf8/The-theta-model-A-decomposition-approach-to-forecasting.pdf), they describe the seasonality test in more detail on page 524.